# Different GPS antennas not working properly on my GPS module

Tags: arduino, pcb, gsm, sim

I have a SIM808 based board. It is working fine with an antenna similar to this: enter image description here

Now I want a smaller one; I bought 3 from Amazon for testing. The same voltage, frequency and dB but none of them fixed a connection with the GPS satellites.

The one I bought: [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BWM4PXNV)

What could be the problem?

I tried different GPS models, voltage is fixed everything is perfect (the older GPS is working fine).

Comment: _"enter image description here"_ -> the link got lost...

Comment: What complex impedance does the antenna present at your required operating frequency. I ask this because circuit boards have a matching circuit that tends to make them only usable with certain antennas. What emission pattern similarities are there? Amazon don't provide data sheets to my knowledge and therefore you are at there mercy. Buy from reputable suppliers who provide data sheets is my strong advice.